# Looking to add layers of Massachusetts State Senator and State Representatives to map?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

Where can I find files of Massachusetts State Senator and State Representatives to add these layers to a map?

Comment: census bureau ?

Comment: found out what their boundaries are, (districts) and add attribute values as needed to the polygons. Look on your states districts maps to see boundaries

Answer (score 1):

[Open States](https://openstates.org/) offers this data.
[Here's Massachusetts' data mapped out](https://openstates.org/ma/).
You can make API calls using Open States' API to generate this dynamically and/or rip the leaflet map/data for static.

Answer (score 1):

The Open States district-shape API is a little shaky in my experience, so I don't use it.  Instead, I use the [Census shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_sld.html).  You need to puzzle out how to map from the Census GEOID (district ID) to the OpenStates district, but it's really trivial IIRC - ping me here if you need specifics.

The one minor downside is that OpenStates tries to be more current - to keep up with redistricting better - by getting their data directly from each state.  Redistricting usually occurs only once a decade.